# Castle ActiveRecord relationship

Tags: c#, orm, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to map the following model with Castle ActiveRecord

- Contact (a person represented by a name and a phone number).
- Group (represents a group of contacts).

A contact can belong to several different groups, but does not have to be in a group.

In the database this i represented as:

Contact

- Id
- Name
- PhoneNumber

Group

- Id
- GroupName

Group_Contact
 - GroupId
 - ContactId

The contact does not need to know which groups it is contained by (maybe it's a mapping requirement, but not a business requirement).

Ideally I'd like to just have a collection of Contacts on the Group class.

I've tried mapping it like this in the Group class

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Contact),
Table = "Group_Contact", ColumnKey = "GroupId", ColumnRef = "ContactId")]
public IEnumerable<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

Which gives me the following exception:
Could not guess relation type for property Group.Contacts

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `IEnumerable<Contact>` use `ICollection<Contact>` (for bag semantics) or `ISet<Contact>` (for set semantics) or `IList<Contact>`